# UPDATE:Posted answers could cause a battery to explode. New user cannot add an answer

Tags: discussion

Found incorrect answers on your site. Posted answers could cause a battery to explode. New user cannot add or correct the answers to protected question. Do I just walk away or what can I do? Thanks.

UPDATE:

The question I refer to is: [Using a 12V battery while simultaneously charging via solar panel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79075/using-a-12v-battery-while-simultaneously-charging-via-solar-panel)

The 3 specific answers to that question are OK because the small solar panel could not overheat a (I assume car size) 12V battery.

My Concern: This question has been viewed 85000 times. It would be helpful to others planning this in general to understand the dangers. I think that is not allowed on this site. Perhaps it would be legal to just comment on Phil Frost's excellent and correct answer.

I would add: A charge controller is required if the solar cell produces more than about 2 watts per each 50 amps of battery Ah rating. Charge controllers limit current as the battery charges to prevent overheating or overcharging. If a (too large) load is added in parallel with the battery, this confuses the controller. It thinks it has a low battery and increases current. That current in turn is divided between the load and the battery. This now unregulated current can (as Phil points out) damage, destroy or cause the battery to explode. Most controllers have separate connections for the battery and the load. Use them.

Comment: Well if you think there's a problem you could add a link to the answer - use the share link below the answer. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual answer(s) that are wrong and dangerous? If we have a link, then someone with good knowledge about battery safety can take a look and take appropriate action (editing answer, contacting the author, etc)

Comment: Can you post a link to the answer?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245641/potentially-dangerous-and-harmful-physically-activity-related-questions-action